# “that's him alright” exact meaning?

Tags: meaning

I tried to Google that up but got no hits.
“that's him alright” - what does it mean?
Is it pure slang or there is a dictionary entry explaning that?

Comment: "Alright", in this context, is a sort of exclamation meaning "for certain".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Alright*** (or all right) in your sentence is used just to add emphasis:

> #### Adverb
>
> 2 used to emphasize how certain one is about something.
>
> - "‘Are you sure it's him?’ ‘It's him all right.’"
>
> #### Usage
>
> There is no logical reason for insisting that all right should be written as two words rather than as alright, when other single-word forms such as altogether have long been accepted. Nevertheless, alright is still regarded as being unacceptable in formal writing
>
> [(Lexico.com)](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/all_right)

Comment: @Em. The usage is also in the link, not another reference.